# Ammonia Vapor Absorption Refrigerator

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

I am working on fabricating the icyball system. I am planning to charge it with the help of convex mirrors. Whether it is necessary to create a vaccum inside the refrigeration closed cylinders before filling ammonia?

Comment: These refrigerators are not very efficient anyway, but for demonstration purposes, it will work, albeit even less efficiently, with residual air.